# How to show 4 product desktop view and 2 in mobile view - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, rwd

In **rwd** theme, when I show **4** products in a row by following code in **catalog.xml**

`<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>` it looks good on **desktop** but on **mobile** view product boxes collapse in each-other.

is there any way to shows **4** products in **desktop** view and **2** in **mobile**.

Please help me to achieve this ?

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1):

1) Firstly, dont update it directly in `catalog.xml` but in `local.xml` of your custom theme.

2) Assuming that the actual block name is:

```
<block type="...", name="block1" template="...">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
</block>

//Now we add another one

<block type="...", name="block2" template="...">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><count>2</count></action>
</block>
```

3) In app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/path to your your phtml

replace the block that calls the block1 with:

```
    <?php $isMobile = Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match( Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent(), $_SERVER); ?>
    <?php if($isMobile): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('block2') ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('block1') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: there is no local.xml in my rwd theme

Comment: you create it in `layout/local.xml`